# Replacing electric cooktop (40 amps) with induction range (50 amps)

Tags: electrical

We are remodeling the kitchen in our new condo (haven't moved in yet).  We would like to use a Wolf induction range which says it requires a dedicated 50 amps.  Our current GE electric cooktop is listed as being on a"double 40amp" breaker.  Can we use the Wolf range instead?

Comment: Have you seen the actual breaker?  Do you know what size the actual installed breaker is, or did 40A just come from documentation on the existing cooktop?

Answer (score 1):

If and only if the wire size going to the current cook top is #8 wire, even then it barely passes.  If not, upsize wire to #6 copper. In either case you must upsize the breaker size to 50-Amp.

Comment: How do you make that work on #8? Is there a special rule allowing #8 at 50A for cooktops?

Comment: Table 310.15(B)(16)  As long as the copper conductor is rated for 75*C.  All breakers carry that rating now.  And not more than three current carrying conductors in raceway or cable.

Answer (score 0):

My old range actually required a 50AMP  my induction range required 40 amps - so I got off easy.

You will need to verify the size of the breaker that is installed - it will be a double breaker (240V) either a ganged (double lever) or a single lever.

Since you are remodeling you can have your electrician rewire that for the proper connection. However the word CONDO tells me that it might be a converted apartment style. In which case the wiring is most likely a 3 wire hookup [L1, L2 and Neutral - note NO GROUND] (you can get ***electrocuted*** in rare circumstances with that) and if your electrician rewires it - by code they will need to upgrade to 4 wires [L1, L2, Neutral and Ground] - and you really should do this regardless for your safety's sake.

As a side note since we are talking rewiring a 240V circuit with 4 wires for your safety - your dryer connection might also be a 3 wire In rare circumstances you can get ***electrocuted*** there also. Have your electrician rewire that for 4 wires as well, L1, L2, Neutral and Ground!